# Replacing function's return type with mapping function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to replace a return type of a function by using a mapping function.
It should look something like this:

```
// typescript 2.9, so no tuple arguments support yet.
type WithNewReturnType<
  F1 extends (...args: T[]) => V,
  F2 extends (arg: V) => MV,
  T,
  V,
  MV
> = ((...args: T[]) => MV);

// use case
const chain = <F1, F2>(f1: F1, f2: F2): WithNewReturnType<F1, F2> =>
  (...args) => f2(f1(...args));
```

F1's return type should match F2's argument type.

There are two problems with the above code:

1. It complains F1 and F2 are unused.
2. It requires 5 arguments instead of 2, like WithNewReturnType.

How to do it with just two arguments keeping the constraint, `R<F1> === A<F2>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around, I've come up with an answer myself:

```
export type Chained<F1, F2> = F1 extends (
  ...args: Array<infer T>
) => infer V
  ? (F2 extends (arg: V) => infer MV ? ((...args: T[]) => MV) : never)
  : never;
```